# HAProxy check CMS and redirect to Varnish

Tags: redirect, varnish, haproxy, rules

I need an help about the configuration of our HAProxy.

this is our configuration:
HAProxy > Varnish servers > CMS servers

what I wish is that the HAProxy the HAProxy checks in the backend if the CMS Server is working properly and the use the varnish server as connection.
is it possible? if yes, how?
thank you very much
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HAProxy backend you can use the `server` option and specify the `addr` and `port` options to define where the check actually goes. For example:

```
backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server varnish1 10.0.0.1:80 check addr 10.1.0.0 port 80
    server varnish2 10.0.0.1:80 check addr 10.1.0.1 port 80
    server varnish3 10.0.0.3:80 check addr 10.1.0.2 port 80
```

The 10.1.0.x addresses are for the CMS.

[The documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#5.2-check) has all of the parameters that can be specified for the check option.

Comment: Thank you!! this is what I meant!